# Objects created from celery task not firing django post_save signal

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, django-signals

I have a celery task that creates a modal object. I'm trying to run some code after the object is created using django post_save signal. but for some reason, the signals are not firing.

models.py

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()


@receiver(post_save, sender=Alert, dispatch_uid="create_jira_issue")
def create_issue(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    //do something here
```

tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def create_alert():
    Alert.objects.create()
```

this is how the code looks like.
the Objects are being created through the celery task. but it's not triggering the post_save signal. any input is appreciated.

Comment: Have you imported signals on ready method in app config?

Comment: @TrueGopnik Yes I have

Comment: Signal is triggered if you are saving Alert outside Celery?

Comment: Signal is triggering outside celery without any issues

Comment: This looks like celery is not working, could you check that?

Comment: celery is working. because celery is creating objects without any issues

Comment: Maybe try, in your task method, calling other method that creates Alert and see if that works.

Comment: @BartoszStasiak Do you mean, move the Alert.objects.create() to outside the task as a function and try calling that ?

Comment: Hi @ArunLaxman any update on this?

Comment: @Benjamin, I don't exactly remember. but i think for me, it was due to celery and django running on different docker containers.